# Angular 2 - Component fails to render table tags properly

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm looking to dynamically load some data into a table. The data will show up onto the page, but it will not be properly formatted within my HTML table. All the text appears on a single line and has no table format whatsoever. I have a custom component with the following information:

## HTML

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <app-books *ngFor="let book of booksArray" [book]="book"></app-books>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have an `@input()` decorator in a child component called `app-books`.

## app-books typescript file

```
  @Input() book: {title: string, author: string, cover_img: string};

  constructor() {
  }
```

## app-books html file

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at your markup, you will see that your `tr` are embedded in `app-books` tag. So your markup is invalid. See

[image]

To resolve this, I suggest you use `[app-book]` for your component so that you can assign it as an attribute of the `tr` element:

```
<tr *ngFor="let book of booksArray" [app-book]="book"></tr>
```

Also, remove `<tr>` and `</tr>` from your `app-book` component markup. See the [Plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/f10V6gsxa6qpC3VIrBM1?p=preview) that illustrates this.

**Edited**

Angular 4 introduced the [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) directive that could be useful in this scenario. But, it does not allow passing an `Input` parameter to the referenced component. See the [There is no way to access inputs or outputs of Components created by NgComponentOutlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15360) issue. But, I've found the [ng-dynamic-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component) package that can do this. So, your code may be:

**Parent component:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Author Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="booksArray" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
            <ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="AppBook" [ndcDynamicInputs]="{book: item}"></ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Row component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tr[app-book]',
  template: `
    <td>{{ book?.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ book?.author }}</td>
  `
})
export class AppBook {
  @Input() book: { title: string, author: string, cover_img: string };
}
```

The `tr[app-book]` selector is important here. It tells Angular to render a `tr` element with the `app-book` attribute. If you specify it as `app-book`, Angular will render the `<app-book>` tag, which is invalid markup. If you specify it as `[app-book]`, Angular will render `<div app-book>`, which is also invalid. See the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjv8bc) that illustrates this.

Comment: Cool! I had thought we couldn't separate any parts of a table into a child component. So you *can not* separate the `tr` from the `table` or `tbody`, but you *can* separate the `td` from the `tr`. Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: This is the route I went with. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @RyanShocker I really like this case and I spent some time to find a better solution. Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the complete `booksArray` to the child component it not only makes it for a better separation of concerns, but it also allows you manipulate that data at a component level.

Try this:

App.html

```
<app-books [books]="booksArray"></app-books>
```

AppBooksComponent.ts

```
export default class AppBooksComponent {
  @Input('booksArray') books: any;
  constructor() {}
}
```

AppBooksComponent.html

```
<tr *ngFor="book in books">
  <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Oddly enough tho, the formatting is still slightly off in the HTML table.